# How to detect client's web browser is Vivaldi?

Tags: javascript

I've tried on getting browser info from javascript - navigator.userAgent, but cannot find any related string with "Vivaldi".

Please help to suggest if there are any other programming method or javascript can be used to detect Vivaldi browser?

Comment: UserAgent is the one

Comment: Why do you need to detect any particular browser? It's not reliable and some vendors are [planning to do away with detailed user-agent strings](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html) anyway

Comment: Sometimes you just need to know what browser is being used. It’s a valid question.

Comment: I’ve heard all the arguments against user-agent, device, feature sniffing etc. and I think the pros far outweigh the the statistically unlikely cons. Obviously, the one-size-fits-all approach is the best default strategy, but like I said… sometimes you just need to know extra info about how the page is being viewed in order to get the job done. If used responsibly and with awareness of the caveats I think there’s nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @maqam7, yes, that's right. Is for browser data analysis.

Comment: Here is post from Vivaldi talking about their user agent string: https://vivaldi.com/blog/user-agent-changes/. Basically see if there is a `Vivaldi` substring in the navigator user agent info

Comment: @GopikrishnaS tks for the link, realy not possible to detect Vivaldi completely, the userAgent has Vivaldi only in some friendly sites, eg duckduckgo.com

Comment: @PhillipYeoKianYong how to fix that problem? please.

Answer (score 4):

Before August 2023, all browsers can be differentiated by checking `navigator?.userAgentData?.brands`.

Since August 2023, Vivaldi tries to make itself indistinguishable from Chrome by stating its own `brand` as "Chrome".

If you're developing a regular website, there's no way to differentiate, but you shouldn't have a reason to care if the user has Vivaldi or Chrome.

If you're developing a chrome extension, you could do this:

```js
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
if (tabs?.[0]?.['vivExtData']) console.log('Vivaldi!')
```

- there are some extension APIs that work only in Chrome, so it's understandable you want to check for Vivaldi.

Answer (score 2):

According to Vivaldi, the userAgent will not have `Vivaldi` in it for a better user experience and mimic Chrome in all sites except a few known ones.

> For the next release of Vivaldi, we have decided to try something different. The problem with our current approach is that with the web being almost infinite, we can’t possibly discover all the websites who have blocks set against us. Thus maintaining a list of sites where we present a non-Vivaldi User Agent is difficult. Instead, we will try doing the reverse. For a handful of sites where we know the label Vivaldi (and our version number) is responsibly used, we will present our full User Agent. Those sites being our own and a handful of interesting alternative search engines: duckduckgo.com, ecosia.org, qwant.com, and startpage.com. Every other site will get a User Agent that appears to be identical to Chrome.

src: https://vivaldi.com/blog/user-agent-changes/

Since you haven't mentioned your use case, assuming you are building sites, the best solution would be to do what everyone does. I recommend building websites agnostic to browsers and devices, but responsive to resolutions and feature support. Almost all of the browsers are running on Chromium these days, except Safari and Firefox (to my knowledge). So they are all going to work consistently across the board. For any given feature, one could always refer to w3c or mdn docs for compatibility and build around that.

Browser detection is also not quite reliable, as there are extensions to spoof the information. Like this extension that mimics a TV agent so one can run youtube console version on it.

On the other hand, once again I don't know your use case, one might benefit from platform detection over browser detection, like catering to mobile and TV users. Even then, if you have a site responsive enough the platform becomes non-essential information.

Answer (score -1):

You can check window size, but it may be incorrect.
Vivaldi has its own sidebar and bottom bar that the others not.
But remember, user can change the window size to prevent detection.

Comment: Ya, this could be another way, but is there any browser features different between Chrome and Vivaldi?

Comment: how does window size relate to detecting what browser the user is on?

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me...

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
    is_vivaldi = 'vivExtData' in tabs[0];
});
```